# Draw Vertical Line QGIS Composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Is there a way to draw a perfectly vertical line in QGIS's Composer. I wanted to created a visual separator between two elements for aesthetic reasons.

I've tried the arrow tool, removing the arrow head and holding the shift / ctrl / alt buttons to see if it will lock it to horizontal or vertical angle but no luck.

The only other alternative I could think of was making and importing an SVG, but I wanted to check here first, as that seemed a bit ridiculous.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draw an arrow and remove its end markers. Then, in the item properties panel for the arrow, expand out the "position and size" group. Set the line's width to 0 for a perfectly vertical line, or the height to 0 for a horizontal line.

Edit:
QGIS 2.5 now allows you to draw a horizontal or vertical line by holding shift while drawing the line.

Answer (score 2):

Along with changing the arrow head, you can set its rotation (shown in the image) to 90 degrees which would give you a perfectly straight vertical line.

[image]

Comment: Hi Joseph - thanks for the reply. Perhaps I'm being a bit over the top, but the 90 degrees would be from the initial position I thought? This would mean if the initial position were slightly wonky so to would the 90-degree-rotated-line? I thought there was an obvious was to snap to perfect horizontals and verticals that I was missing but perhaps there isn't =/ Thanks